# Sudden change of the odometer reading in Perodua viva elite

Tags: electrical, gauges, odometer

I have a Perodua Viva Elite auto gear car from December 2011. It was manufactured in 2011. The odometer reading the day before yesterday was 72000 but I noticed yesterday morning it reads near 61000. I have not touched the battery or any electrical item so what could be causing my mileage to change?

Comment: That's nuts.  Wish I had an answer for this one.

Comment: My guess is that the memory controller on the PCB that's driving the odometer is dying.